# what is major version does QBOE supports?

Tags: quickbooks, quickbooks-online

1) What is the Current Major version for QuickBooks online? Because up to  version 6 QBOE works fine and  after that it’s  throwing error like "Problem communicating with QuickBooks Online".

2)As per the OSR(Onscreen Reference)  QuickBooks online supports Multi-currency feature. Since, the OSR Currency(ListId and FullName) columns belongs to QBO  major version 8.0, we could not access these  fields due to the problem mentioned above(i.e. We can access QBO version up to 6).

3) In OSR AccountModReq doesn't have any column mentioned as online. But when we try to update the Account data, it was updated with the below Warning message 
    "A field that is not supported was included in the request. The remainder of the request was processed normally, but the unsupported field was ignored".

```
Are the columns mentioned as online in OSR are the only supported columns for QuickBooks online? Please confirm.
```

Note: We are  connecting the QBOE through QBSDK 12(QBFC) using java code.

Answer (score 0):

> 1) What is the Current Major version for QuickBooks online? Because up
>   to version 6 QBOE works fine and after that it’s throwing error like
>   "Problem communicating with QuickBooks Online".

If you're talking qbXML, it supports up to 6.0

> 2)As per the OSR(Onscreen Reference) QuickBooks online supports
>   Multi-currency feature. Since, the OSR Currency(ListId and FullName)
>   columns belongs to QBO major version 8.0, we could not access these
>   fields due to the problem mentioned above(i.e. We can access QBO
>   version up to 6).

Correct. QuickBooks *Online* does not support multi-currency through the API.

> 3) In OSR AccountModReq doesn't have any column mentioned as online.
>   But when we try to update the Account data, it was updated with the
>   below Warning message "A field that is not supported was included in
>   the request. The remainder of the request was processed normally, but
>   the unsupported field was ignored".

QuickBooks Online does not support AccountModRq via qbXML.

Make sure you have the OSR set to 6.0 if you're developing for QuickBooks Online.